# Why doesn't height reset

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to use jquery to reset the value of a height for a table, in the following #ExpandGrid_Header is a table and #MainContent_ExpandGrid is also  a table

```
        $("#ExpandGrid_Header").css("height", $("#MainContent_ExpandGrid tr:nth-child(1)").css("height"));
        alert($("#ExpandGrid_Header").css("height") + " __ " + $("#MainContent_ExpandGrid tr:nth-child(1)").css("height"));
```

The following comes out in the alert

```
59px __ 25px
```

But I obviously am trying to get 25px __ 25px

The following is the only css I have on the first table

```
#ExpandGrid_Header 
    {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
```

And the following is my html

```
                <table id="ExpandGrid_Header" style="border: 1px solid;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Attribute 1</td>
                            <td>Attribute 2</td>
                            <td>Attribute 3</td>
                            <td>Attribute 4</td>
                            <td>Attribute 5</td>
                            <td>Attribute 6</td>
                            <td>Attribute 7</td>
                            <td>Attribute 8</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: "But I obviously"... it doesn't seem very obvious at all. Perhaps you can provide more relevant CSS? Maybe make a working demo of your problem?

Comment: That is not your complete HTML nor CSS, since you are referencing an element with an id of "MainContent_ExpandGrid". Also, just because you set the height in CSS, doesn't mean that will be the height that results when you measure it, since the measured height may take things like line-height, font-size, padding, borders, etc. into account as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the height with the height() function instead of from the css value.

```
$("#ExpandGrid_Header").height($("#MainContent_ExpandGrid tr:nth-child(1)").height());

alert($("#ExpandGrid_Header").height() + " __ " + $("#MainContent_ExpandGrid tr:nth-child(1)").height());
```